Will removing the FOREGROUND_SERVICE from the Android app manifest (but not the related code) pass Google's review?
Our android app update has been rejected a few times due to our declaration/justification of FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK not meeting their requirements. The rejection notices aren't clear exactly what the problem is so we decided to remove the library that uses this permission to avoid issues with too many rejections.
However, we have one more library that declares the FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission (not any of the specific permissions added in Android 14: https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/fg-service-types). This is not a permission that's in the required declaration but our rejection mentions it must also be removed if no other foreground service permissions are used.
Since we don't need this permission or related services from the library, we removed them from our merged app manifest by adding the following to our app manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" tools:node="remove" />
<service android:name="com.some.library.SomeService" tools:node="remove" />

However, the library we use still has code (although never called) that initiates FOREGROUND_SERVICE. We were wondering if anyone has experience with Google Play review rejecting apps if the permission is not in the manifest but exists in the code.
Our app runs correctly and all related functionality works after making this change.
Thank you for your time!
